# Value of $z$ so that the series converges

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\left(z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Detrmine the value of $z$ so that the series converges

I believe that the series converges when $|z|<1$, but taking the $\lim_{n\to \infty}|\left(\frac{1}{n^2}(z^n+\frac{1}{z^n})\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}|<1$ I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: Maybe try to write this as two sums (one with $z^n$ and one with $\frac{1}{z^n}$), see when those converge for starters

Comment: How do you get $<1$ for that limit?

Comment: Hint: Does the series converge at $z=2$? At $z=\frac13$? At $z=1$? (To be answered in this order.)

Comment: Another hint: compare $f(z)$ and $f(\frac{1}{z})$. That tells you that there is only one way to make this work.

Comment: Using : if $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ a complex series then if $lim_{n\to \infty}(|a_n|)^{1/n}<1$ then the series converges absolutely

Comment: @helplessKirk AFAIAC, I would rather use that if $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges then $a_n\to0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the series only converges when $|z|=1$, since we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{n^2}$$ which converges, but for $|z|\ne 1$, consider $|z|\lt 1$, then we can see that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}(\frac{1}{z^n})=\infty$$ also by analysing the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}|(\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{z^n})^\frac{1}{n}|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^\frac{2}{n}}|\frac{1}{z}|=|\frac{1}{z}|\gt 1$

Comment: seemingly the $z^n$ part behaves nicely when $z\lt 1$, but not when $z\gt 1$, and we end up with the same situation

Comment: This forgets the unit circle $\{z\mid |z|=1\}$.

Comment: @Did true yes, sorry I have edited

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|\neq 1$, the absolute value of $\frac{1}{n^2}\left(z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}\right)$ tends to $\infty$, hence the series cannot converge. In the other case, $z=e^{i\theta}$, the series is convergent since the absolute value of $z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$ is bounded by $2$, and we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n+z^{-n}}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_2(z)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1/z).$$

Comment: I saw that  representation in wolframalfa too. Unfortunately I don't know what $Li_2(z)$ represents.

Comment: It is the dilogarithm function, it is just defined as the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$.